The TriggerDagRunOperator in airflow does not trigger the second dag
I recently read more about
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator

if one day is successful, another one should start.
with DAG(
        'delete_customer_retention',
        default_args=args,
        description='delete customer retention before insert',
        catchup=True,
        start_date=datetime(2024,5,26),
        #end_date=datetime.today(),
) as dag_delete_customer_retention:
    
    delete_customer_retention = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='create',
        postgres_conn_id=postgres_conn_id,
        sql='drop table if exists mart.customer_retention CASCADE;'
    )

    trigger_d = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='triger',
        trigger_dag_id='sales_mart'
    )

    delete_customer_retention >> trigger_d

in theory, after delete_customer_retention is executed, the dag sales_mart should be executed, but a picture appears where the dag with deletion has worked, and the second one is in the status - queued, then no movements on statuses occur... What am I doing wrong?
Dag's sales_mart:
with DAG(
        'sales_mart',
        default_args=args,
        description='Provide default dag for sprint3',
        catchup=True,
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7),
        end_date=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1),
) as dag:

I don't understand why the second dag doesn't start
